# How to separate two images in the same row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

do you know how to separate two images in the same row?
Thank you so much for your help.
I will post the image under this sentence.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0xcF.jpg)

```
<div id="portfolio">
            <div class="container-fluid w-75">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center"> 
                     <div class="zgrade">
                       <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/szgrade/zgradaA.jpg" alt="..." />
                             <h2 class="zgrade-txt" style="color:white"> Zgrada A </h2>
                             
                     </div>
                     
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center"> 
                     <div class="zgrade">
                       <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/szgrade/zgradaB.jpg" alt="..." />
                             <h2 class="zgrade-txt" style="color:white"> Zgrada B </h2>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Css

```
.zgrade {
  position: relative;
  
  border: 1px solid #333;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 745px;
}

.zgradeimg {
  width: 500px;  
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.zgrade:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.zgrade-txt {
  position: absolute;
   top: 250px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%;
```

Edit: Added CSS code, I tried adding br and span in HTML code.

Comment: add a margin to an element, or gap to the flexbox?

Comment: It seems like you're using a css library. Please add which one

Comment: Sorry, I added CSS code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, I increased w of the container from 75 to 80, but I needed to add a new class in CSS (that would be w-80).

Answer (score 0):

We could use simple css to add a margin to the element. This would create empty space between the elements.
Add this to your external stylesheet or in your html file(best place is head):

```
<style>
    .img-fluid {
        margin-right: 20px;  /*feel free to change this to any amount*/
    }
</style>
```

or

```
style="margin-right:20px"
```

Margin is space outside of an element, which mostly acts like white space. It is counted in the element size but it is outside the border and background color does not effect it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I solved the problem just now, I increased w of the container from 75 to 80, but I needed to add a new class in CSS (that would be w-80).